# How to Integrate LDAP with Gitorious running on a CentOS 6 Server?

Tags: ldap, centos6, gitorious

**How to Integrate LDAP with [Gitorious](https://gitorious.org/) running on a CentOS 6 Server ?** 
I've a CentOS 6 Server running on a Virtual Machine in which I have configured Gitorious which is running properly with all the features. 
Now I want to integrate LDAP with Gitorious. How can I do it ? 
**please provide me step-by-step solutions**

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be supported natively: https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/LdapIntegration